Where would modern bridge players draw the line in the following paradigm?
Take a hand like ♠ AK ♡ K ♢Txxxx ♣ Txxxx. In the old days (about 100 years ago), some experts might have evaluated the hand at 2.5 quick tricks and two five card suits and opened it 1 diamond (or 1 club). I doubt that modern experts would do this, since it only has 10 high card points.
Improve the hand slightly to ♠ AK ♡ K ♢Jxxxx ♣ Jxxxx. Now it (technically) has 12 high card points, as well as the two five card suits. Would modern experts open this hand?
If not, how much would the hand have to be improved? Perhaps to ♠ AK ♡ K ♢Qxxxx ♣ Jxxxx? Or might the key improvement be to ♠ AK ♡ Kx ♢Jxxxx ♣ Jxxx, shortening the club suit but protecting the formerly singleton K of hearts, pushing its value closer to "3"?.

Based on Mycroft's answer below, it appears that the key improvement for the 12 point hand might be protecting the king of hearts so that it actually is half a quick trick.

That's still horrible.  But it might get opened by the "all 12s that aren't 11s" crowd.  I would be happy to pass this dreck even so, and see if the opponents play the misfit with all the top honours in short suits.  Playing a strong NT, I am not as conservative as I am playing a weak NT (where 1m openers need to "say something"), but I still am more willing to pass sub-minimums if I'm opening a minor.

Two statements here, before it goes into the weeds:

One of my rules (which nobody I trust disagrees with) is "Once you have decided your hand is an X, it remains an X no matter what happens.  It could be a good X, a bad X, and incredible X or a horrible X, but it never becomes not-X."  X can be "opening bid", "game force", "single raise", "balanced hand", whatever.  Here, we're talking "opening bid".
Quick tricks aren't what your question states they are.  Your example hands have 2 only QT, until your last one which is 2.5 (which I will admit is "closer to 3" than 2).  Quick tricks are (quote from Wikipedia, my emphasis, but many others online):

2 quick tricks = AK of the same suit
1 1/2 quick tricks = AQ in the same suit
1 quick trick = A
1 quick trick = KQ in the same suit
1/2 quick trick = Kx (not K singleton)



This is because a singleton K will never take a "quick trick".  It needs the A or Q or it's as good as the 2.  Kx will take a trick half the time depending on where the Ace is.
Now:
Anybody who required 2.5 QT (or, like K/S and Goren, stated that 2.5 QT was a mandatory opener, could open 1.5 or 2 if...) would never open these hands as they're awful, 10 Milton HCP or no.  Even 12.  Even in 1940, minors got outbid by majors, there are no extras, most HCP are outside the suits, the spades are inflexible,...
The switch to Milton Work Count doesn't change the analysis.  Remember, Miltons don't take tricks; they don't win partscore battles; they're just a convenient way to start the analysis of a hand.  In discussions, people will start with (unless they just give the whole hand) "I had a [shape] [hcp] count, with..." but the "with" is the important part.
What that "with" is, depends on known tools, skill at using them, and need to use them.  Using LTC as a secondary tool, "I had AK K 55, so 7 losers, but my suits are minors".  Using "in-out", "I had AK K 55, my 'out' honours are good, but there's nothing 'in'."  Or you might get the kind of analysis I used above.  Or...
All this to say that "the switch from QT-based primary evaluation to HCP-based primary evaluation" just would not be any reason to change whether the hand is opened or not.  If "modern experts" don't open this hand, it wouldn't be because it "only has 10 HCP" (see AK843 K8432 8 64, for instance, probably an auto-open), it's because your example hands are too awful to commit to "being an opener".
But having said that, they might be opened now - for two reasons:

Openings are just getting lighter and lighter.  In standard, "decent 11s and all 12" is pretty common, and at least you have a plan (1♦, then rebid clubs).  Less likely the 10 (effective 7) counts would be, but the 12s might - but they'd be "awful openers", at least until partner shows a huge fit for one minor (and even then, I'd expect my last decision would be "do I sacrifice?")  But if they are opened, it's because partner knows they can be opened and caters to (or has the system cater to) them.
Many players don't play a Standard system, and do so so that they can open lighter yet.  Modern Precision players open "10-15", especially NV, and would open many "9s that look like 10s".  They might open 1♦ on those hands (having a safe 3-if-necessary-♣ rebid if the auction goes competitive).

How much would you have to change it to get a majority in flight A to open?  At least moving the ♥K into a minor.  Or switching one of the suits to spades.  Or make it a real 13 (QJ in a minor?)  Not sure.
It's good to notice these hands are awful, and that single-evaluation methods fail on some hands, QT, HCP, LTC, ZAR or whatever.  But know that experts (modern or otherwise) never use a single method of evaluation in their analysis, and never make a judgement based on a single factor (okay, "never bid slam with two quick losers"; "never" never means never in bridge).  You shouldn't either.

I think you're asking for a single rule for a question which is multi-faceted (as illustrated by Mycroft's extensive answer).
After 'Open all 13 points hands', the choices get contextual below 13 points. Obviously that doesn't mean never open beneath 13, but one shifts from the 'I am strong enough to open' path to one of many 'My hand has shape-merit' bids. Now one looks for Offensive-strength backed bids matched to 'reasons' for bidding: possible ruffing potential/part-scores/sacrifice/lead-direction/pre-empt, etc.
The opening hands (above) are bad because of their low offence to defence ratio (ODR). They're for defending rather than playing and no reason to open. (You'd just need Partner with A in Clubs or Diamonds (67%) to defeat opponent's 4H, while a club void with D-AKxxxx for 6D quite unlikely and you'd discourage partner's desirable spade lead by bidding diamonds). Conversely, when partner's strong they've a bid of their own, so you never miss a game or slam.
I'd say it wasn't possible to evaluate many 12- point hands against a rule, or find a line, but better to measure Offensive/defensive merit (trick-taking & losing potential) in Context (vulnerability, seat, reason-for-bidding). Experts judge those biddable low point-count openers from feature more than formula although feature-based evaluations are varied -  Where points are in long suits? Are short suits a strength or weakness? What can opponents make? Bid or Defend? etc.
